# Rails API Worker on Heroku with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, worker, rails-api

I'm working on setting up a Worker in a Rails API app to send emails through the SendGrid API after form submission. I've been using the following tutorial as a guide.

https://itnext.io/sidekiq-overview-and-how-to-deploy-it-to-heroku-b8811fea9347

When I try to submit the form, I get a response immediately - but no emails are sent. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

**app/controllers/leads_controller.rb**

```
...

def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    if @lead.save
        @venues = Venue.all
        HardWorker.perform_async(@venues, @lead)
        render json: @lead, status: :created, location: @lead
    else
        render json: @lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

...
```

**app/workers/hard_worker.rb**

```
class HardWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: false

    def perform(venues, lead)
        @venues = venues
        @lead = lead

        @venues.each do |venue|
            if venue.email
                UserNotifierMailer.send_lead_email(venue, @lead).deliver
            end
        end

        UserNotifierMailer.send_signup_email(@lead).deliver
    end
end
```

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec rails s
release: bin/rake db:migrate
hardworker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 2
```

**Update with heroku logs**

```
2019-05-14T16:07:19.832606+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4ojjes8 HardWorker JID-69a69142b893a183306ddb69 INFO: start
2019-05-14T16:07:19.833556+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4ojjes8 HardWorker JID-69a69142b893a183306ddb69 INFO: fail: 0.001 sec
2019-05-14T16:07:19.843658+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4ojjes8 WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"class":"HardWorker","args":["#<Venue::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005583e0e39680>","#<Lead:0x00007fbfa0114880>"],"retry":false,"queue":"default","jid":"69a69142b893a183306ddb69","created_at":1557850039.8114436,"enqueued_at":1557850039.8117154},"jobstr":"{\"class\":\"HardWorker\",\"args\":[\"#<Venue::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005583e0e39680>\",\"#<Lead:0x00007fbfa0114880>\"],\"retry\":false,\"queue\":\"default\",\"jid\":\"69a69142b893a183306ddb69\",\"created_at\":1557850039.8114436,\"enqueued_at\":1557850039.8117154}"}
2019-05-14T16:07:19.864496+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4ojjes8 WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "#<Venue::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005583e0e39680>":String
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882424+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4ojjes8 WARN: /app/app/workers/hard_worker.rb:9:in `perform'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882428+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:192:in `execute_job'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882441+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in process'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882444+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882445+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882447+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:164:in `block in process'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882448+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:137:in `block (6 levels) in dispatch'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882450+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:109:in `local'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882452+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:136:in `block (5 levels) in dispatch'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882453+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:43:in `block in call'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882455+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882457+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882458+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882459+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882461+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:42:in `call'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882463+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:132:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882464+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:250:in `stats'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882465+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:127:in `block (3 levels) in dispatch'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882467+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:8:in `call'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882469+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in dispatch'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882470+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:74:in `global'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882472+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:125:in `block in dispatch'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882473+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:48:in `with_context'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882475+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:42:in `with_job_hash_context'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882476+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:124:in `dispatch'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882478+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:163:in `process'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882480+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:83:in `process_one'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882481+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:71:in `run'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882483+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
2019-05-14T16:07:19.882484+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.2.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
2019-05-14T16:10:24.013315+00:00 heroku[hardworker.1]: Restarting
2019-05-14T16:10:24.025034+00:00 heroku[hardworker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-05-14T16:10:24.930345+00:00 heroku[hardworker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-05-14T16:10:24.942407+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4nwe3lw INFO: Shutting down
2019-05-14T16:10:24.942431+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4nwe3lw INFO: Terminating quiet workers
2019-05-14T16:10:24.942534+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4ojji50 INFO: Scheduler exiting...
2019-05-14T16:10:25.442840+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4nwe3lw INFO: Pausing to allow workers to finish...
2019-05-14T16:10:26.444798+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gt4nwe3lw INFO: Bye!
2019-05-14T16:10:26.590745+00:00 heroku[hardworker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-05-14T16:10:40.274601+00:00 heroku[hardworker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec sidekiq -c 2`
2019-05-14T16:10:40.864028+00:00 heroku[hardworker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-05-14T16:10:52.096992+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gs793pw3g INFO: Running in ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
2019-05-14T16:10:52.097024+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gs793pw3g INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2019-05-14T16:10:52.097026+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gs793pw3g INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2019-05-14T16:10:52.097208+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gs793pw3g INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.2.7 with redis options {:id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-4", :url=>"redis://redistogo:REDACTED@pearlfish.redistogo.com:9778/"}
2019-05-14T16:10:52.115881+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gs793pw3g WARN: Sidekiq 6.0 will require Redis 4.0+, you are using Redis v3.2.12
2019-05-14T16:10:52.116074+00:00 app[hardworker.1]: 4 TID-gs793pw3g INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
```

Comment: Does `hardworker` in `hardworker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 2` work? It should be `worker`, right?

Comment: On Heroku it doesn't matter what the worker process is called. `worker` is just a convention. `hardworker` should be fine. What do you see when you `heroku logs -t -d hardworker`? Do you have a `hardworker` dyno running?

Comment: Updated with logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you're enqueueing `HardWorker` with `@venues`, which is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that gets serialized to a string by Sidekiq.

When enqueueing Sidekiq jobs, you want to pass the primary keys of records instead of the records themselves. `ActiveJob` abstracts this away, but when using Sidekiq directly, never pass `ActiveRecord` objects. Use primitives instead.

In your case, I think you want something like this:

```rb
# controller
HardWorker.perform_async(@lead.id)

# worker
def perform(lead_id)
  @venues = Venue.all
  @lead = Lead.find(lead_id)
  # ...
end
```

Also, I strongly recommend setting up error tracking with Sentry or Honeybadger so you're notified when exceptions like these are encountered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Helps so much, and totally makes sense as well! Thanks!